# Get variable lengths differ error fixed for string variable

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following code:

```
xtabs(c("violentIncidents", "nonviolentIncidents", "allPart1s") ~ District + pnum, data = cadincmerge_ag4wk)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = c("violentIncidents", "nonviolentIncidents",  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'c(District)')
```

District consists of the following values:

```
Central
Eastern
Northeastern
Northern
Northwestern
Southeastern
Southern
Southwestern
Western
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we may need `cbind` and variable names without quotes

```
xtabs(cbind(violentIncidents, nonviolentIncidents, allPart1s) ~ 
         District + pnum, data = cadincmerge_ag4wk)
```

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
data(mtcars)
xtabs(cbind(cyl, gear, carb) ~ vs + am, mtcars)
```

Comment: This works - however how to I split the reported values apart? Meaning that the number does not combine violentIncidents, nonviolentIncidents, allPart1s but where for each Pnum, we have three reported values per district?

Comment: @user13203033 The `xtabs` returns a multidimensional array when there are more than one variables on the lhs of `~`.  I assume that the question was about how to fix the issue